# просмотр за день modx revo

Tags: cms, modx, revo

как вывести ресурс у которого больше просмотр за день modx revo

Просмотры считаю вот так: [[!Hits? &hit_keys=`[[+id]]` &tpl=`hitsID`]]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
[[!Hits? &parents=`0` &depth=`10` &limit=`1` &outputSeparator=`,`]]
```

Должен вывести самый популярный ресурс от родителя с id=0, глубина просмотра 10

https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/hits

Comment: а мне нужно вывести самый популярный за текущий день